# NullPointerException when calling Window.setVisible()

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, window

I have a heavy GUI application. Every time I start it, I get the following stack trace from the EventDispatchThread:

```
14:30:04:115 >> java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mercury.ftjadin.support.jfc11.cs.JTableCS$CellEditorListenerRegistrar.addListener(JTableCS.java:151)
    at com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.abstr.ObjectCS.registerListeners(ObjectCS.java:2736)
    at com.mercury.ftjadin.infra.DefaultCustomClassManager.onCreate(DefaultCustomClassManager.java:575)
    at com.mercury.ftjadin.hooks.WToolkitHook.onCreate(WToolkitHook.java:23)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.createComponent(Toolkit.java)
    at java.awt.Component.addNotify(Component.java:6650)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2565)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
    at javax.swing.JTable.addNotify(JTable.java:683)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:738)
    at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:664)
    at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:470)
    at java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:860)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1591)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1543)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:843)
    at ... my_classes_stack_trace
```

I tried to debug it in java's source to find what I did wrong and what required object is `null`, but I got stuck since I don't have the source for `com.mercury.ftjadin` package...

BTW, the application runs OK regardless this exception, but I would like to resolve this anyway..

Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Comment: Can you post the code? Maybe you have a loop (   at java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2576)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4693) )

Comment: As I said, It's a heavy GUI app, containing (only the GUI part) tens of classes. The problem is I was a total java beginner when writing the first classes and I might do some poor programming I'm trying to trace back now. so, no. I guess posting the entire code is impossible...

Comment: I would check the JTableCS your using in the GUI and check if there is any problem in adding the listener to it (In case you have access to it).

Comment: I don't have access to JTableCS source. The jar is available in the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem had something to do with QTP's java plugin.

The exception was not thrown since I have removed this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  new window.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Viewing a window works perfectly. It only happens sometimes when the `Window` has a `com.mercury.ftjadin.support.jfc11.cs.JTableCS` instance contained in it.

Comment: It happens on `frame.setVisible(true);`. `frame`'s class extends `JFrame`.

Comment: Like you have written, `class window extends JFrame{}` ?

Comment: NO. It's `class MyFrame extends java.swing.JFrame {}` which in turn `extends java.awt.Frame extends java.awt.Window`...

Comment: then try `new MyFrame.setVisible(true);` I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

check for the null object.

example:

```
if(object!=null)
{
  //enter code here
}
```